# Fragment with different size than the nav host fragment

Tags: java, android, navigation-architecture

I'm using the navigation architecture component in my single activity app and it works fine but what I'm facing is that in one of the fragments I need to have another fragment that takes about 60% of the initial fragment size (60% of the nav host fragment). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now change the nav host fragment size programmatically whenever I need to